# .htaccess redirect enquiries for expired pages

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have two friends with existing websites hosted  by companies that provie a webpage-building service + hosting. One is .asp, the other .html.

I want to help create new Wordpress sites for them both.

After the new sites have gone live, we will want to stop paying the old hosts.

I understand that I can set up a 404 redirect to send every enquiry for a page that doesn't exist on the new server to a dedicated 404 Error page.

What I would like to do, is have an anquiry for ANY individual 'old' page, be redirected to the new page on the Wordpress site.

I understand that .htaccess instructions can redirect enquiries for pages hosted on the hosting account. But can .htaccess take an enquiry for a now non-existant  page and redirect it to an existing page. e.g;
on old site there was a page mydomain.com/testimonials.asp
on new site there is a page mydomain.co/testimonials
The old hosting account is closed, and the .asp page no longer exists

Can an .htaccess redirect pick up that enquiry for an .asp page (or .html equivalent) and redirect it to the appropriate page which IS on the server?

Or am I asking the wrong question? Maybe it should be
"Can I load files with the .asp extension to thw Wordpress hosting, and then have .htaccess redirect the enquiry?

I hope I've explained this properly. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.